# How should I call same ajax route url for every ajax function even if it is in another controller in laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I have already called ajax in route for one controller like:-

```
Route::post('ajaxupdate','Scheduling\ScheduleController@SaveBooking');
```

Now,I need to call ajax url for another controller. Do i have to create another route function for second controller differently (like I have called for first controller) or is there any way I can call ajax url from one file only for all controllers.

Comment: This will work for all controllers and views. No need to create another route for it.

Comment: you can call `'Scheduling\ScheduleController@SaveBooking'` from any url, but you cannot call different methods from same url

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a controller from the Laravel container through [`app()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-app) function. Then you can call the controller method from other controllers / services etc..

```
$controller = app('App\Http\Controllers\Scheduling\ScheduleController');
$request = app('Illuminate\Http\Request');
$request->query->add(['param' => 'value']);
$controller->SaveBooking($request);
```